# Assumptions that can be made for $f(x) + xf '(x)\leq 0$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I am wondering if we can make any assumptions about a function $f$ i.f.f. it satisfies
$$f(x) + xf '(x)\leq 0 \qquad\forall \;x>0\;?$$

Comment: Consider $g(x) = x\cdot f(x)$. How is that related?

Comment: I mean, the function belongs to some family of functions if and only if the inequality is satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(x) + xf'(x) = x'f(x) + x f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\Big( xf(x)\Big) \le 0.
$$
That means $xf(x)$ gets smaller as $x$ gets bigger.  The quantity $x\cdot\dfrac 1 x$ stays the same size as $x$ gets bigger, so $f(x)$ must be getting smaller by comparison to $1/x$.

Answer (score 1):

In a more general way, being $x>0$ and rewriting the differential inequality as
$$
f'(x)\leq -\frac{1}{x}f(x)
$$
if we apply [Gronwall's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall's_inequality) for $a>0$ we have
$$
f(x)\leq f(a)\exp\left(-\int_a^x\frac{1}{t}dt\right)=\frac{a}{x}f(a),\qquad\forall x>a.
$$

Comment: is the converse to Gronwall's inequality true? I.e., in our case does the following hold
$$\frac{a}{x}f(a) \geq f(x) \implies f'(x) \leq -\frac{1}{x}f(x)?$$

Comment: @Chadman: don't think so.